# How to build Ext JS code by classes bundle instead of generating just one app.js file

Tags: extjs, google-closure-compiler, sencha-cmd

I'm working on a Ext.js project which requires me to produce code for a production environment.

I can combine and compress all js and css files in production, but some feature are implemented by "Ext.require" which means actually I don't need to compress all js files to just one "app.js".

For example, in MVC structure, there are 3 main js files:

1. CoolController.js
2. CoolModel.js
3. Cool.js

In "CoolController.js", I require "App.ui.Awesome" class. In this case, if I compress all of them; then the require method makes no sense to me.

So my question is, is that possible that I can write some bundle config like Grunt.js does, build "Cool Classes" to one file while excluding the ext.js and App.ui.Awesome files and then I could compress them in the way I want? One feature implemented by 3 files to one js file output?

Answer (score 1):

require.js can serve two purposes. Each can be used independently:

1. dependency management
2. module loader

When managing dependencies, requirejs handles correctly the loading order of other scripts. However, when un-optimized, requirejs uses multiple script tags. This is contrary to the [performance optimization of minimizing files](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/compressing-javascript). For most production uses, a single javascript file performs better than multiple files.

One major exception to this rule is the case where an application is large enough to dynamically load modules for specific areas. In this case the performance gain comes by delaying loading of script sources and thus save both on the retrieval time as well as the parse time and memory impact. However even in this case, a module is usually made up of multiple requirejs modules which should themselves be optimized.

In short, you should always optimize your source into as few files as the project demands. In a production environment there is almost no reason to keep source files separated by class.